# How to combine 2 queries in 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query 1:

```
SELECT Year(TranscDate) AS 'Year', 
       Month(TranscDate) AS 'Month', 
       SUM(TranscPayment) AS Revenue 
FROM MembershipTransc
GROUP BY Year(TranscDate), Month(TranscDate)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Year(ExpenseDate) AS 'Year', 
       Month(ExpenseDate) 'Month', 
       SUM(Expense) AS TotalExpenses 
FROM OperatingExpense
GROUP BY Year(ExpenseDate), Month(ExpenseDate)
```

table 1:

```
Year || Month ||Revenue

2020 ||  4   ||   80.00

2020 ||  5   ||   40.00
```

table 2:

```
Year || Month || TotalExpenses

2020 ||  4   ||   20.00

2020 ||  5   ||   20.00
```

Desired Output:

```
Year || Month ||Revenue  || TotalExpenses

2020 ||  4   || 80.00   ||  20.00

2020 ||  5   || 40.00   ||  20.00
```

Comment: Have a look at `JOIN`, Shantie. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: normally we have to use "join", but the prerequisite is that these two tables sharing one identical column to allow this happen. It might be helpful to give the relationships between these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a `join`:

```
SELECT r.yyyy, r.mm, r.revenue, e.TotalExpenses
FROM (SELECT Year(TranscDate) AS yyyy, Month(TranscDate) AS mm
             SUM(TranscPayment) AS Revenue 
      FROM MembershipTransc
      GROUP BY Year(TranscDate), Month(TranscDate)
     ) r JOIN
     (SELECT Year(ExpenseDate) AS yyyy, Month(ExpenseDate) as mm, 
             SUM(Expense) AS TotalExpenses 
      FROM OperatingExpense
      GROUP BY Year(ExpenseDate), Month(ExpenseDate)
     ) e
     ON r.yyyy = e.yyyy AND r.mm = e.mm;
```

If you have months with data in one table but not the other -- and you want those months in the result set -- then use an `OUTER JOIN` of some sort.

Note:  Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Use single quotes only for string and date constants.